# Android Bluetooth LE Connection issue with other bluetooth devices

Tags: android, cordova, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

First of all, there's no problem with iOS, but the problem occurs when the app is running on Androids.
 
There's a BLE device that does pair / notification / write / read.
 
It seems all good until other bluetooth devices are connected and paired or synced. 
For example, if the android phone is restarted (or Bluetooth is off and on again), my BLE device works great with the app.
If I open fitbit app and sync a fitbit device, then my device cannot connect anymore. (and not pairing as well) 
Not only for fitbit but also for samsung smart watch, the same thing happens. 
Anyone recommendation will be appreciated. 

Tested with Android 6. Samsung GS6 and Nexus 5.

Update 1: 
After synced with fitbit, I get the following messages from my app when connecting to my device.

```
11-11 09:02:41.811   781  1599 I ActivityManager: Killing 21073:com.android.chrome:privileged_process0/u0a34 (adj 13): empty #17
11-11 09:02:41.822 21010 21010 W cr_ChildProcessConnect: onServiceDisconnected (crash or killed by oom): pid=21073
11-11 09:02:41.838   781   952 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 21073
11-11 09:02:41.838   781   952 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.chrome/org.chromium.content.app.PrivilegedProcessService0 in 1000ms
11-11 09:02:41.857   781  1226 I ActivityManager: Start proc 23634:com.android.chrome:privileged_process1/u0a34 for service com.android.chrome/org.chromium.content.app.PrivilegedProcessService1
11-11 09:02:41.902 21010 21010 W .android.chrome: type=1400 audit(0.0:21068): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[1799361]" dev="sockfs" ino=1799361 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
11-11 09:02:41.902 23644 23644 W Binder_1: type=1400 audit(0.0:21069): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[1799361]" dev="sockfs" ino=1799361 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
11-11 09:02:41.902 23644 23644 W Binder_1: type=1400 audit(0.0:21070): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[1799361]" dev="sockfs" ino=1799361 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
11-11 09:02:41.905 23634 23634 I cr_ChildProcessService: Creating new ChildProcessService pid=23634
11-11 09:02:41.908   781  2450 I ActivityManager: Killing 21102:com.android.chrome:sandboxed_process0/u0a34i52 (adj 13): empty #17
11-11 09:02:41.912 21010 21010 W .android.chrome: type=1400 audit(0.0:21071): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[1799361]" dev="sockfs" ino=1799361 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
11-11 09:02:41.919 23634 23644 I cr_LibraryLoader: Using linker: org.chromium.base.library_loader.ModernLinker
11-11 09:02:41.920 21010 21010 W cr_ChildProcessConnect: onServiceDisconnected (crash or killed by oom): pid=21102
11-11 09:02:41.941 23634 23646 I cr_LibraryLoader: Loading chrome from within /data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk
11-11 09:02:41.965 22521 22521 I System.out: writeCharacteristic(4, 8, AQAAAA==)
11-11 09:02:41.967   781  1226 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 21102
11-11 09:02:41.967   781  1226 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.chrome/org.chromium.content.app.SandboxedProcessService0 in 1000ms
11-11 09:02:42.016 23634 23646 I cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 95 ms (timestamps 5253-5348)
11-11 09:02:42.016 23634 23646 I cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "54.0.2840.85", actual native library version number "54.0.2840.85"
11-11 09:02:42.016 23634 23646 I chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(151)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
11-11 09:02:42.027 23634 23646 E libEGL  : validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
11-11 09:02:42.028 23634 23646 I Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/21/15, 369a2ea, I96aee987eb
```

After this, it does one more reading then disconnected. 
If I goto bluetooth app and 'clear data', then it works fine again.

Comment: Seems weird. Exactly what kind of error messages do you get? Does logcat print anything? HCI snoop log?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I haven't got the issue since because fitbit and the smart watch are from someone else. I returned them and my device is working perfectly fine pretending nothing happened. :(